# How can I get client IP in IBM MobileFirst8

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mfp

I use MFP.Server.getClientRequest().getRemoteAddr() API in adapter

but it get WebServer(IHS) IP not client IP

I know its mean last proxy ip

How can I get client actual IP?

Answer (score 1):

You can take one of two approaches:

1. If the Webserver sets a `X-Forwarded-For` header, then use  `MFP.Server.getClientRequest().getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")` , to obtain the client IP.
2. Capture the client IP in the client-side ( mobile) code and embed it in the request payload that fires. Obtain this value in the IBM MobileFirst Javascript code.